# Recursive checkout to specific version in git

Tags: git

Currently, I am in the develop branch, but i want to switch to previous version, ex(release_v5.1) Meanwhile, I want all my submodules in current develop branch also switch to release_v5.1. Is that possible to do it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout --recurse release_v5.1` will update all submodules to their proper commits.

shorthand for `git checkout --recurse-submodules`

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules

Comment: I tried this one already, it only change current branch, but my subdirectories did not change at all... any other tips?

Comment: Are the submodules initialized? `git submodule update --init`

Comment: yea, it is. I already had those submodules in my directory. but they didn't switch after I called the command that you provided.

Comment: No errors? I've seen that happen when the submodule isn't clean. ie modified files or new files